# Transaction is getting committed even if i donot use @transactional in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to integrate spring with hibernate  and trying to use session factory in dao layer
my test class looks like this :

```
package com.transaction;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.transactionManagement.java.Employee;
import com.transactionService.service.TransactionService;

public class TransactionManagementTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Bean.xml");
        Employee emp = (Employee)applicationContext.getBean("employee");
        emp.setFirstName("vivek3");
        emp.setLastName("krishna2");
        emp.setAmount(2000);
        TransactionService ts=(TransactionService) applicationContext.getBean("transactionService");
        ts.insertEmployee(emp);
    }

}
```

and I created service and dao interfaces
dao:
    package com.Transaction.dao;

```
import com.transactionManagement.java.Employee;

public interface Transaction {

    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp);

    public Employee getEmployeebyId(Integer employeeIdentifier);

    public int updateSalaryfoeEmployee(Integer employeeIdentifier,Integer Salary);

}
```

Service:

```
package com.transactionService.service;

import com.transactionManagement.java.Employee;

public interface TransactionService {

    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp);

    public Employee getEmployeebyId(Integer employeeIdentifier);

    public int updateSalaryfoeEmployee(Integer employeeIdentifier,Integer Salary);

}
```

corresponding dao & service impl:

```
package com.Transaction.dao.impl;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.Transaction.dao.Transaction;
import com.transactionManagement.java.Employee;

@Component("transactionDao")
public class TransactionDaoImpl implements Transaction {

    @Autowired
    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp) {
        sessionFactory.openSession().save(emp);

    }

    public Employee getEmployeebyId(Integer employeeIdentifier) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Employee) sessionFactory.openSession().get(Employee.class, employeeIdentifier);
    }

    public int updateSalaryfoeEmployee(Integer employeeIdentifier,
            Integer Salary) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query q= (Query) sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("update Employee set Salary=:salary where id=:id")
                .setParameter("salary", Salary)
                .setParameter("id", employeeIdentifier);
        return q.executeUpdate();

    }

}
```

service impl:

```
package com.transactionService.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.Transaction.dao.Transaction;
import com.transactionManagement.java.Employee;
import com.transactionService.service.TransactionService;


@Component("transactionService")
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService{

    @Autowired
    private Transaction transactionDao;

    public void insertEmployee(Employee emp) {
        transactionDao.insertEmployee(emp);

    }

    public Employee getEmployeebyId(Integer employeeIdentifier) {

        return transactionDao.getEmployeebyId(employeeIdentifier);
    }

    public int updateSalaryfoeEmployee(Integer employeeIdentifier,
            Integer Salary) {
        return transactionDao.updateSalaryfoeEmployee(employeeIdentifier, Salary);
    }

}
```

corresponding Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring 
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

 <import resource="DataSource.xml"/>

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.Transaction.dao"></context:component-scan>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.Transaction.dao.impl"></context:component-scan>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.transactionService.service"></context:component-scan>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.transactionService.service.impl"></context:component-scan>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.transactionManagement.java" />

 <bean id="employee" class="com.transactionManagement.java.Employee"></bean>
 <bean id="transactionDao" class="com.Transaction.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl">
 <property name="employee" ref="employee"></property>
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="springTransactionTest" class="com.transaction.SpringTransactionManageTest">
 </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.transactionManagement.java" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Data source file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<bean id="dataSource"
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://PRAMOD-LAPTOP;databaseName=TestMart1;" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

output trace:

```
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:37 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@25f38edc: startup date [Sun Mar 05 13:20:37 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Bean.xml]
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [DataSource.xml]
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionDao': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.Transaction.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Bhaskar\SpringTransactionManagement\target\classes\com\Transaction\dao\impl\TransactionDaoImpl.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.Transaction.dao.impl.TransactionDaoImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [Bean.xml]]
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@490ab905: defining beans [dataSource,transactionDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,transactionService,employee,springTransactionTest,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:38 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:39 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:39 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.18.Final}
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:40 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 05, 2017 1:20:40 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: insert into Employee (amount, first_name, last_name) values (?, ?, ?)
```

*Question*: I did not use @transactional but still insertion is happening.can anybody explain this

Regards,
Bhaskar

Comment: if you throw an excpetion after ts.insertEmployee(emp);.. does it rollback?

Comment: Your setup is flawed in many ways, it works probably due to the fact you have auto commit on your connection. However as stated your setup is flawed, you are using `openSession` without properly managing the session (or transaction) which will lead to connection leaks (at some point your application will die because your db doesn't allow for anymore connections). Next even if you had used the proper approach it was still wrong due to the usage of the wrong transaction manager (you should be using `HibernateTransactionManager` and not `DataSourceTransactionManager`.